# How do I control whether a user can edit other users' permissions in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, permissions

We're stuck on TFS 2010 for the time being and making the best of it, so please reach waaaay back into your memories for this one. :)

### Problem

As an admin users, I've configured permissions for all the users and roles, and then removed myself from the administrator roles (which others still have).

However, it looks like I can still edit permissions.

### Question

- What permissions / factors determine whether I, as a user, can edit permissions for other users and roles within TFS? (e.g. "How do I stop users from being able to edit their own or others permissions?)

### Potential Leads

- The users accounts that I'm trying to restrict are admins on the local box. If this is where TFS pulls this permission from, that could be the problem. Researching further.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I think it's a combination of several different permissions:

There are several contributing factors:

- In the team project, there is a setting called "Edit Project-level information"
- In the collection, there is a setting called "Edit Collection-Level Information"
- There is a server level [Team Foundation Server] group, which has a Team Foundation Server Administrators permission group.
- Administration console users are also added to the services group, which is part of the administrators group.
- Local administrators are included in the Team Foundation Service Administrators group by default.

So the solution in our case was to:

- Remove builtin admins from the team foundation administrators group
- Remove my user account from the console users
- Uncheck the "edit project-level information" and "edit collection-level information" from the TFS groups that I'm a part of.